# Pass currently selected list item from bootstrap plugin selectpicker into JS

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to `JS`, I'm trying to access a selected value from a select list using the `selectpicker` plugin from bootstrap.

Currently my code gives me the entire list rather than just the currently selected item.

```
<div class="form-group">
                <select class="selectpicker" name="applicationSelect">
                    <option value="1">app 1</option>
                    <option value="2">app 2</option>
                    <option value="3">app 3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

Then in my script.js file I have:

```
var appName = $('select[name=applicationSelect]').val(1).text();
```

The retrieved value will then be based onto an `Ajax` event, but I'm struggling to find a working example doing what I'm trying to do.

How do I retrieve only the currently selected item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
 $('select[name=applicationSelect]').val()
```

If you specify `val()` with a parameter, you are actually setting the value. Without parameters, the method will just return the current value.

You can find more information [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_val.asp).

Comment: Using just .val() only returns the selected number e.g `1` ?

Comment: I may need to edit more of my code, I'll read up on that link thank you.

Comment: It will return the `value` inside the `option` tag